# How to serve a set of files from nginx only if a domain name has a keyword

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a usecase where a files are grouped and each group can be served for a specific domain name in nginx server. I am not sure how can I acheive that. `valid_referer` is something which is similar but that works on referer header not on original url. Is there anything similar to `valid_referer` like `valid_origin` ?

with valid refererer my config looks like this. But would prefer to handle same via origin condition instead.

```
location /landing/jack/ {
        valid_referers ~\.codejack\. ~\.jacktest\.;
        if ($invalid_referer) {
            return 403;
        }
    }
```

**Edit**: files are grouped via location. So each location can say to be linked to one or more origins.

```
location /landing/google/ {
        valid_referers ~\.google\.;
        if ($invalid_referer) {
            return 403;
        }
    }

location /landing/stackoverflow/ {
        valid_referers ~\.stackoverflow\.;
        if ($invalid_referer) {
            return 403;
        }
    }
```

All I need is conditional way where I use origin url instead of referer url.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **nginx server blocks**

Example in your config file you can have like this.

```
server {
    server_name sub1.yourdomain.com;
    root /var/www/sub1;
    index index.html;
}

server {
    server_name sub2.yourdomain.com;
    root /var/www/sub2;
    index index.html;
}
server {
    server_name sub3.yourdomain.com;
    root /var/www/sub3;
    index index.html;
}
```

For more information, https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

Comment: actually these are additional static folders over ones which are same across domains....is there any other way?